# Does the cross product of $\mathbb{R}^3$ produce a 1-vector or a 2-vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, geometric-algebras

I think that, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, 1-vectors and [2-vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(geometry)) have 3 components. Here, also, the cross product $\vec a \times \vec b$ and the [exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) $\vec a \wedge \vec b$ of vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ have the same components (and so their norm is the area of the parallelogram delimited by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$). I also think the're related by the following:

$$\vec a \times \vec b = *(\vec a \wedge \vec b)$$

where $*$ is the Hodge star, which means they're [Hodge duals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual).

All of this means that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ it's easy to mistake a 1-vector for a 2-vector (and conversely).

So, my question is: does the cross product produce a 1-vector (ie. an "oriented length"), a 2-vector (ie. an "oriented area"), or neither?

Comment: I would think it's a 2-vector, and that we actually have $\vec a\times \vec b = \vec a \wedge \vec b$, without the dual (which would make it a 1-vector). At least I've always thought of the cross product as signifying an oriented area.

Comment: @Arthur I also thought $\vec a \times \vec b = \vec a \wedge \vec b$ (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), but it can't be, because the cross product is not associative, whereas the exterior product is

Comment: The identity $\star (a \wedge b) = a \times b$ suggests that $a \times b$ is a $1$-vector. The Hodge dual of a $p$-form is an $n-p$-form, where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: I assume that "the cross product results in a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$" is not the answer you're looking for. Something else you could observe is that the cross product imposes this unnatural choice of "handedness" on the space, which is another indication it must result in a 1-vector. The exterior product is more natural, since it does not require this choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of viewing the differences and relationships is through the formalism of Geometric Algebra.  There the 3D cross product and the wedge product can be related by an explicit multiplicative duality relationship

$$\begin{aligned}\mathbf{a} \wedge \mathbf{b}&=   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_2 \\    b_1 & b_2 \\ \end{vmatrix}+   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_3\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_3 \\    b_1 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}+   \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3\begin{vmatrix}   a_2 & a_3 \\    b_2 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix} \\ &=   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_3\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_2 \\    b_1 & b_2 \\ \end{vmatrix}+   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_2\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_3 \\    b_1 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}+   \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3\begin{vmatrix}   a_2 & a_3 \\    b_2 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix} \\ &=\mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3\left( {      \mathbf{e}_3\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_2 \\    b_1 & b_2 \\ \end{vmatrix}-   \mathbf{e}_2\begin{vmatrix}   a_1 & a_3 \\    b_1 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}+   \mathbf{e}_1\begin{vmatrix}   a_2 & a_3 \\    b_2 & b_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}} \right) \\ &=   I (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}).\end{aligned}$$

where $ I = \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3 $ is a unit pseudoscalar for the 3D space.

The wedge (exterior) product, a [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector), or grade-2 multivector, has a direct interpretation as an oriented area.  The cross product, as the dual of that bivector, has a magnitude and direction that can also be interpretted as an oriented area, but it is a different beast since it is a grade-1 multivector.  The pseudoscalar factor $I$ that relates the wedge and cross products is geometrically different than a unit scalar (i.e. $I^2 = -1$), which has implications for the applications of the products.

This distinction is one that is important in some contexts.  For example, in physics the cross product isn't called a vector, but is called a pseudovector, since it has different transformation properties than a normal vector.

Comment: I think I just learned that the cross product of 2 vectors is a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector), and the cross product of a vector and a pseudovector is a vector. Is a __grade-1 multivector__ the same thing as an "ordinary" vector? (I assume multivectors are elements of the graded exterior algebra, ie. the exterior algebra, ie. the algebra generated by the exterior/wedge product). Is a __grade-1 multivector__ the same thing as a [1-blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_(geometry))?

Comment: Geometric algebra is more general than exterior algebera, and a multivector in geometric algebra includes elements of the exterior algebra, but also sums of such elements (or sums of products).  For example, for vectors a, b: 1 + a /\ b is a multivector that has grades 0, and 2.  The wedge in GA is not a fundamental product, but a derived one (it's the antisymmetric product (ab - ba)/2).  I wrote grade-1 multivector to be unspecific, since it includes both vectors and pseudovectors, but yes, it is the same thing as a 1-blade.

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you!